# Possible null reference argument for parameter 'connectionString' ind 'DbContextOptionsBuilder'

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, health-check

I am working on a .NET ASP CORE application with a SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) database.

I added my DatabaseContext to the IServicecollection in the `startup.cs` file like this

```cs
services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(_config.GetConnectionString("MvcMovieContext")));
```

and this worked perfectly.

But when i wanted to implement Healthchecks with the `Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks;`, I suddenly had an ERROR at the line above.

`Possible null reference argument for parameter 'connectionString' in 'DbContextOptionsBuilder SqlServerDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseSqlServer(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder, string connectionString, Action<SqlServerDbContextOptionsBuilder>? sqlServerOptionsAction = null)`

[screenshot of the error inthe code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Mfu2.png)

I tried to implement the HealthCheck service of Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks but suddenly my connectionString (or IConfiguration _config) is nullable.

Any idea how to fix it?

Note: if I want to check if the connectionString is null and try to save it in a variable(like this: 'string conn = _config.GetConenctionstring("MvcMovieContext");' ), it gives an error: "converting null literal or possible null value to non-nullable types"

---

**SOLVED:** Solved by the comment from **@MindSwipe**:

You can simply check for it, like `var connectionString = _config.GetConnectionString("MvcMovieContext"); if (connectionString is not null) { ... }`

Thanks!

Comment: What's your code of appsettings ? Do you define the MvcMovieContext?

Comment: It's not an error, it's a warning. And it's because [`_config.GetConnectionString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationextensions.getconnectionstring?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) *can* return null, if no connection string with that name exists. You can either ignore it and otherwise ensure that there is a connection string with that name, or check if it's null and either recover or exit with a nice error message.

Comment: @MindSwipe how to ignore it? If I run the code it exits with error. Also: string conn = _config.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"); gives an error "converting null literal or possible null value to non-nullable types"

Comment: You are using Entity (dbContext) and need to add AddDbContextCheck().  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/health-checks?view=aspnetcore-7.0#entity-framework-core-dbcontext-probe

Comment: @jdweng thanks. that was actually my next step, but I still need to resolve this error, where i can't add the DbContext in my 'startup.cs' file

Comment: You can simply check for it, like `var connectionString = _config.GetConnectionString("MvcMovieContext"); if (connectionString is not null) { ... }`

Comment: When a project is first started with Entity a connection has to be made to the database.  It  sound like you may be trying to do the health check before the connection is made.  You may need to move the health check to a location after the connection is established.   Your startup has to be after following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application#set-up-ef-6-to-use-localdb